# Weld ignores producer

Tags: java, jboss, cdi, weld

I'm trying to deploy a war into a JBoss AS 7.1.1 server and the deploy fails while trying to inject the EntityManager:

```
17:44:48,037 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."c3e.war".WeldService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."c3e.war".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 1 exception:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [EntityManager] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject xyz.beans.UploadImpl.em]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:275)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:244)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:346)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:331)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:366)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Normally I would expect that this would result from Weld being unable to find a suitable bean to be injected. However, I define a producer for the EntityManager thus:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Resources {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="myUnit", type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Produces
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }
}
```

The injection-point about which it complains appears as follows:

```
@RequestScoped
@Named("upload")
public class UploadImpl implements Upload, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    EntityManager em;
}
```

In another project exactly the same setup worked just fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question answered in a comment above: the @Produces annotation was imported from the wrong package. Thank you, Antoine Sabot-Durand!

Answer (score 0):

Just a long shot, but there are two types of annotations: `javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped` and `javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped`. My guess is that your producer is annotated with the JSF annotation instead of the CDI one.

As the CDI spec says:

> 1.2.6. Relationship to JSF JavaServer Faces is a web-tier presentation framework that provides a component model for graphical user interface
>   com- ponents and an event-driven interaction model that binds user
>   interface components to objects accessible via Unified EL. This
>   specification allows any bean to be assigned a Unified EL name.
>   **Thus, a JSF application may take advantage of the sophisticated context and dependency injection model defined by this
>   specification.**

This means you're free to inject CDI beans to the JSF managed beans, however the opposite is not true. The container things that the `

If you want to use CDI you have to chage your annotations to come from the `javax.enterprise.context` package.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm afraid the @xScoped annotations in my app are all already imported from the javax.enterprise.content package, so that wasn't the problem.

Comment: And do you have both classes in the same module?

Comment: And you're sure that your `@Produces` is not a `javax.ws.rs.produces` ?

Comment: Aha! That was the problem. Thank you!